# How to split a Debian package and install the split off one automatically

Tags: apt, package-management, debian, split

I have a Debian package, said A, and I would like to move some files out of A and create a new package B for the split off files.

A is installed on the system and could be upgraded by "apt dist-upgrade". Is there any way to automatically "install" B when I upgrade A by "apt install" or "apt dist-upgrade"?

I checked the [PackageTransition](https://wiki.debian.org/PackageTransition) page and my scenario is exactly the case #7. No dependency between package A & B, so I can't let A depend on B.

Comment: To split I'd just re-package. You can cause newer package to be chosen by name/version (easiest is via PPA used by systems where you want it to be used). You didn't provide a reference to PackageTransition page (search engine found word in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ProposedMigration & https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/NBS but I don't see connection, so why not provide a link to what you mean?)

Comment: Generally, A and B should not provide the same files. However, your description implies that you want B to be a subset of A. If true, then then A and B would *conflict* with each other. Package conflicts must be listed in the control file. Package "replaces" must also be listed in the control file. If you want B to replace A...but A still exists...then you are going to confuse a lot of users. That confusion alone may cause the Debian high poobahs to refuse the change. There are many per-case possibilities , but without detail there's no point going farther.

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to provide the link. I edited the question so that now it links to https://wiki.debian.org/PackageTransition.

Comment: @user535733 In fact A & B don't conflict with each other. I would say A is a super set of libraries, and now I would like to have better granularity for the packages and move some files out of A to B. After that A & B are independent with each other.

Comment: Sorry, I'll be more clear: Apt will replace A with B when B's control file includes `Breaks A (<<[version])` and `Replaces A (<<[version])`, as you already saw in column #4 of case #7. Those flags tell apt what to do (replace A with B). However, I'm just repeating the documentation, so what element of your question do I seem to be missing?

Comment: Said A version 0.1 has two files, X & Y. I move Y to B (version 0.1) and keep X in A (version 0.2). The system already has A version 0.1 installed. Now I would like to upgrade A (from 0.1 to 0.2) by apt upgrade, and I want B to be installed automatically during the upgrade. Note there is no dependency between A & B, so that I can't let A depend on B to install B.